# Add command to bash history when opening new terminal tab

Tags: bash

I want to open a new tab in the terminal application (`gnome-terminal`, `io.elementary.terminal`, ..), execute the command via `--`, and see the command in the bash history, so I tried:

```
$ bash --version
GNU bash, version 5.1.16(1)-release (x86_64-pc-linux-gnu)

$ gnome-terminal -t foo -- bash -i -c 'history -s ls; bash'
```

but when I press `PageUp` in the newly created terminal `ls` neither `history -s ls` is not last used command in bash history. Why?

Comment: I'm not entirely sure what you're asking about but it feels like it might be related to [is-it-possible-to-make-writing-to-bash-history-immediate](https://askubuntu.com/questions/67283/is-it-possible-to-make-writing-to-bash-history-immediate). FWIW I use the solution described in [this answer](https://askubuntu.com/a/115625). Good luck!

Comment: I simplified my question, thank you for links also, I will look at them.

Comment: BTW, use `exec bash` instead of just `bash` so your new copy of bash _replaces_ the one started with `-c` instead of being its child. (Sometimes bash will do this optimization automatically, but being explicit is more reliable)

Comment: BTW, don't use the `sh` tag for questions that are firmly about bash.

Comment: I added `exec` and it works as expected: `$ gnome-terminal -t foo -- bash -i -c 'history -s jabadabadu; exec bash'`. Appreciate a lot!

Comment: Well, for terminal app `konsole` it works by replacing `--` with `-e` `$ konsole --new-tab -e bash -c -i 'history -s works; exec bash'` so it looks like `--` support is not implemented.

Comment: And for `io.elementary.terminal` it works by replacing `--` with `-e` and adding apostrophes `io.elementary.terminal -t -e "bash -c -i 'history -s works; exec bash'"`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Missing `exec`:

- `$ gnome-terminal -t foo -- bash -i -c 'history -s works; exec bash'`
- `$ konsole --new-tab -e bash -c -i 'history -s works; exec bash'`
- `$ io.elementary.terminal -t -e "bash -c -i 'history -s works; exec bash'"`

works as expected.